# Sinch push notifications are not turning on after unregistering devicetoken

Tags: ios, swift, sinch

I am having one feature in application via which user can stop receiving notifications from sinch. But after turning off notification when i try to make it on user still not getting notifications for chat messages

I use following function for allowing user to receive notifications from sinch

```
let sinchUserID:String = userID as String

    self.sinchClient = Sinch.client(withApplicationKey: SINCH_APPLICATION_KEY, applicationSecret: SINCH_APPLICATION_SECRET, environmentHost: "sandbox.sinch.com", userId: sinchUserID)

    self.sinchClient!.setSupportMessaging(true)

    self.sinchClient!.enableManagedPushNotifications()
    // or
    self.sinchClient!.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true)


    self.sinchClient!.delegate = self

    self.sinchClient!.start()

    self.sinchClient!.startListeningOnActiveConnection()

    self.sinchClient?.setPushNotificationDisplayName(ALERT_TITLE)


    self.push = Sinch.managedPush(with: SINAPSEnvironment.development)
    self.push?.delegate = self
    self.push?.setDesiredPushTypeAutomatically()


    self.push?.setDisplayName(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userFirstname") as! String)

    self.push?.setDesiredPushType(SINPushTypeRemote)
    self.push?.registerUserNotificationSettings()

    if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "newMessageStatus") == 0
    {
        self.sinchClient?.registerPushNotificationDeviceToken(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "deviceTokenForSinch") as! Data, type: SINPushTypeRemote, apsEnvironment: SINAPSEnvironment.development)
    }
    else
    {

        self.sinchClient?.unregisterPushNotificationDeviceToken()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, after calling unregister method you need to close sinch client connection too.

```
sinch_client?.unregisterPushNotificationDeviceToken()
sinch_client?.terminateGracefully()
sinch_client = nil
```